# Not able to redirect back to alexa after successful login from my application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, alexa-skills-kit

When I click "Enable" for my skill from https://alexa.amazon.com I am redirected to my application login page, after entering email/password and successful authentication I am redirecting user to

> https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/link/M2SH60C21FLV91?vendorId=M2SH60C21FLV91&state=A2SAAEAEOlVnPYTaS9OqN_iQmxOIpEBkLSBUPLDHJGzHc_ALJ02fPLzMm9OYOMG9mpSuDVg3_O3fgpSE5iCfh3XCLBs0oTay3Eqr6CEXpU7eDf_11PeUJCk839z0cxc8djFlxbLUr_CINPUNtVoHfzpn3Ztwl4OE-2dcKmqLiza6C9cr7Ca8-8UmEdshagKsue4lYkyWFiFwx-Yg452QHIY0DpnG1rtbanQgW5MjgbTaR3-MPy7QBIodnF_SnbtXpWb69_R3HOlGHPoaJgIbi2yr1lc-fIJbJ8B8Zbzm0mMi2IocOg4fDrFlwQ6ZRUXzeWB6ZapbxfeO4UR3h8Cr3P9_efaRFFgD4NZPL3DkAdlSF2XlAmKIpg5xr3u25jt-vHZi50QWJYgZYLDCJFqrnDoGSVIwLGz1vKFnZCkAYm7ioJ_emq5JtkfBVQaxg2mH2_pcvadbE8DgufJCt0QkDMp94eyRbYKp2uKsdVZNuV_PwGdb1AFVQhzDqbiE0pyMfbjSpWjcTM8CAbdfSGsbxJ3ipcSV6LSjbokH1KP5vLAAVr5wQIRSDA&access_token=WFA0UWlxcTFCZVZnTmJmUmdldUF3dVFwdG1VSGM0aWJSODB1OUVkNTdUST06a2F1c2hhbEBuaWNoZXRlY2guaW46NjM2NDY0MzM2OTAwNzU3NjYy&token_type=Bearer

but it gives me JSON response

> "{"httpRedirectLocation":"https://skills-store.amazon.com/api/skill/link/M2SH60C21FLV91?access_token=WFA0UWlxcTFCZVZnTmJmUmdldUF3dVFwdG1VSGM0aWJSODB1OUVkNTdUST06a2F1c2hhbEBuaWNoZXRlY2guaW46NjM2NDY0MzM2OTAwNzU3NjYy&state=A2SAAEAEOlVnPYTaS9OqN_iQmxOIpEBkLSBUPLDHJGzHc_ALJ02fPLzMm9OYOMG9mpSuDVg3_O3fgpSE5iCfh3XCLBs0oTay3Eqr6CEXpU7eDf_11PeUJCk839z0cxc8djFlxbLUr_CINPUNtVoHfzpn3Ztwl4OE-2dcKmqLiza6C9cr7Ca8-8UmEdshagKsue4lYkyWFiFwx-Yg452QHIY0DpnG1rtbanQgW5MjgbTaR3-MPy7QBIodnF_SnbtXpWb69_R3HOlGHPoaJgIbi2yr1lc-fIJbJ8B8Zbzm0mMi2IocOg4fDrFlwQ6ZRUXzeWB6ZapbxfeO4UR3h8Cr3P9_efaRFFgD4NZPL3DkAdlSF2XlAmKIpg5xr3u25jt-vHZi50QWJYgZYLDCJFqrnDoGSVIwLGz1vKFnZCkAYm7ioJ_emq5JtkfBVQaxg2mH2_pcvadbE8DgufJCt0QkDMp94eyRbYKp2uKsdVZNuV_PwGdb1AFVQhzDqbiE0pyMfbjSpWjcTM8CAbdfSGsbxJ3ipcSV6LSjbokH1KP5vLAAVr5wQIRSDA&token_type=Bearer"}"

and page stops, it does not enable and redirect back to alexa giving success message.

I have to manually copy-paste the url which I get in above json response, then only my account is linked.

Can anyone help why I am not directly redirect and getting the successfully linked page? Why I have to manually copy-paste the url?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot pass [accesstoken](/questions/tagged/accesstoken) as a query param in the redirect url. Appending **#** before the [accesstoken](/questions/tagged/accesstoken) will work.

```
...IRSDA#access_token=WFA...
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed # after vendorId.

Also I had to take full url as below. 
"https://pitangui.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAA"

Answer (score 0):

I am able to redirect now.
I missed "#" after vendorId.

"https://pitangui.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAA#state=xyz&access_token=XXXXX&token_type=Bearer"

Reference url: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html#h3_login_req

Thanks all