# Alexa: We were unable to link at this time

Tags: oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

We are creating alexa skill and trying to do account linking. We have setup the below steps so far for account linking :

1. Setup Authorization URI API 
   https://[abcapp].herokuapp.com/userdetails/accountlinking
2. For Authorization API we are redirecting on AWS account login URL. Please see below URL 
   https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id={0}&scope=profile&response_type=code&state={1}&redirect_uri={2}

Here redirect_uri is our custom signup URL 
https://[abcapp].herokuapp.com/userdetails/signup

3. In signup page we are calling web request for url https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token to get access_token and refresh_token
4. In signup page we ask user to input details and save these details in our database for future interaction with alexa skill to manage user details in database
5. After successfully authentication, we are redirecting on following URL :
   https://pitangui.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=[VenderID]&token_type=Bearer&access_token={0}&state={1}&code={2}

When we are trying to connect alexa skill, I am successfully able to login with AWS , after that I am able to enter user details on signup page. Now we are redirecting user to alexa linking status page but we are getting error as "We were unable to link at this time"

Please see attached screenshot: [image]

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324066/not-able-to-redirect-back-to-alexa-after-successful-login-from-my-application?rq=1)?